# Import OpenCV module to Android Studio blocked by "Nothing to Show"

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV in an AndroidStudio to start creating an application that will be processing images from the camera.

In short, I setup a new Android Studio project based on Java code and went to File -> New -> Import Module to import the OpenCV SDK for Java. After that, I tried to update the main project's settings to add the OpenCV module as a dependency, but I'm seeing "Nothing to Show" whereas others are seeing the opencv imported module as an option to add. The expected behavior was to see the opencv imported module and to be able to add it as a dependency to be able to then reference the OpenCV classes in code, but actually the module is not visible for some reason. I think I'll ask this community if anyone has any better ideas and will provide you with references to what I've tried already, noting that the Android studio shown in the references is a bit older than what I have so the screenshots may not match up perfectly, but the same process was followed.

Thanks for any help in advance.

I see articles describing the process, but it looks like Android Studio has been updated quite a bit and some of them may be out of date. 
For reference, followed this video tutorial showing how to setup an Android OpenCV project.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aT-eXXFPD60&list=PLowDvns8uiBRVGTf3aSdf-h6F9eiA6n2p
Also, tried to follow this article, which is pretty much the same step and same blocker, https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c.

This is a screenshot showing how I imported the OpenCV project:
[Imported OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANZQh.png)

Screenshots of the blocker step "Nothing to Show" showing for the modules available:
[Tried to add as module, but getting "Nothing to Show"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adm9I.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55937338

The solution is to import OpenCV from the 'sdk' folder instead of the 'sdk/java' folder.